# Updating WAMP 2.0

Tags: php, wamp

I'm currently running WAMP 2.0 on a Windows server and it has PHP Version 5.2.5.  I would like to update WAMP to the latest version but more importantly update PHP to 5.3.x so that I can take advantage of all the namespace goodness.

I was wondering if anyone had any pointers for going about this and any pitfalls I should look out for when I do update.  Will I need to update my extensions?  Can I just download the latest version and drop it in to the WAMP PHP bin directory?

Any all insights on this would be helpful.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So I'd love to help but I haven't been successful at upgrading. I followed the instructions here: http://www.dotkernel.com/php-development/how-to-upgrade-wamp-to-php-5-3-4/ to no avail. phpinfo() still thinks I have 5.3.0 for some weird reason.

I noticed I didn't have the php5apache.dll files. I tried copying them from my old install, but maybe they're different for different php versions?

Comment: Had a really bad experience trying to upgrade WAMP. I had to basically restore the PHP directory in order to get my setup going again.  I'm thinking about just moving everything over to a new box instead.